# Command substitution / word splitting within du

Tags: bash

I would like to calculate the size of a directory tree I am going to compress for archiving. I can't for the life of me figure out/feel how the word splitting or command substitution (which I've tried using to remedy the problem) in bash is functioning.

I want to exclude several directories. I place the arguments, which will also be passed to tar in the same manner, in a variable:

```
exclude_opts="--exclude='VirtualBox VMs/Windows 7/*'  
--exclude='Software/*'  
--exclude='LSTC/*'"
```

I then reference this in my call to du

```
$ du -sb $HOME $exclude_opts

38711578819 /home/patrick  
du: cannot access `VMs/Windows': No such file or directory  
du: cannot access `7/*"': No such file or directory  
38711578819 total
```

ok; `$exclude_opts` is being word split for some reason. How do I fix this? All my attempts have failed.

I would like to do this from within the same file; no `--exclude-from`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *really* need to use arrays when collecting arguments like this. Arrays will treat whitespace properly:

Update: removing the single quotes and "/*" from the exclude options

```
exclude_opts=(
  "--exclude=VirtualBox VMs/Windows 7"
  "--exclude=Software"
  "--exclude=LSTC"
)

du -sb "$HOME" "${exclude_opts[@]}"
```

Comment: While your solution does fix the white space problem (thank you for the good answer to the question), it introduces a new problem where du does not recognize the options you feed it.

    $ du -s "$HOME"
    37G /home/patrick
    37G total

    $ du -sb "$HOME" "${exclude_opts[@]}"
    37G /home/patrick
    37G total

Comment: +1, but I would also note that the double-quotes in `"${exclude_opts[@]}"` are significant; things will go terribly wrong without them.

Comment: @Patrick, after a quick test, need to remove the single quotes and "/*" from the exclude options. Please try again.

Comment: Single or double quotes does it for me; no variable substitution here. It was the wildcards pointed out earlier by @Hai-Vu. The command now functions as intended. Thank you both for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simulate your situation and found out that the following works:

```
--exclude="Windows 7"
```

These do not work:

```
--exclude='Windows 7/*'
--exclude='VirtualBox VMs/Windows 7/*'
```

Basically, it works if I only include the immediate directory, no wildcard. My system is a Linux server with kernel version 2.6.9.